# Find/ls caching

Tags: find, ls, cache

It seems as though the first time I run `find` or `ls` on a directory, it takes a while to work. But, each time thereafter, it is fast, as though a list of the directory's contents has been cached or indexed somewhere.

Is there a way to preserve this cache across reboots of the computer?

Comment: It is indeed cached.  Linux uses unused memory as cache and buffers (that's one reason you should always have some swap, even with "enough" RAM).  The free-command shows you how much is available.  Not sure it's much point in caching between reboots, much can change between boots.  How about making a cron-job to run with lowest priorety every 10,30 minutes, to simply go through all your files?  Should keep the cache relatively up-to-date at all time.  Also think there's a way (for kernel) to detect file-changes.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [vmtouch](http://hoytech.com/vmtouch/) to add files to your page cache (disk cache).

Put `nohup vmtouch -dl <files or directories> &` in your `/etc/rc.local` file to add and lock files into your page cache on boot. If you want to add files to your page cache, but don't want to lock them into memory, use the `-t` flag instead of the `-ld` flags.

For more information on the page cache, look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/what-is-the-significance-of-linuxs-disk-caching-mechanisms), [here](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html), and on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

Comment: That command doesn't seem available in Ubuntu - is there an alternative I can try?

Comment: @Richard It is very easy to compile vmtouch yourself: Install the `build-essential` package. Download [`vmtouch.c`](https://raw.github.com/hoytech/vmtouch/master/vmtouch.c). Run `gcc -O2 -o vmtouch vmtouch.c` or `make vmtouch` and you get the binary `vmtouch` which you can then copy for example to `/usr/local/bin` or call by `./vmotouch`.

Comment: @Richard I don't use Ubuntu, so I haven't tested this and take no responsibility but googling "Ubuntu mvtouch" brought up this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~pg-radadia/+archive/vmtouch).

Comment: @jofel, yes, it was easy enough to compile - thanks. I just prefer to use packages when possible.

Comment: @Evan, correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't using `vmtouch` as a on-boot command slow the whole works down? My hope had been to preserve a cache across boots rather than (expensively) regenerating it each time.

Comment: I don't know of a way to preserve the page cache across boots and it is doubtful that one exists. If there was a way to do this (presumably by writing the page cache to a disk), it would be susceptible to data loss (somebody could change the disk contents without booting your OS). Also, it wouldn't necessarily be faster; you would still have to load the data from the disk into memory.

Answer (score 2):

"Preserve across reboots", I doubt it. But you can trivially rebuild the cache on booting, which accomplishes almost the same thing minus a small delay.

Create a file `/etc/cron.d/rebuild-fs-cache` and put the following in it:

```
@reboot root /usr/bin/nice -n 19 /usr/bin/ionice -c 3 -t /usr/bin/find / >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This uses `nice` and `ionice` (which should be installed by default, and definitely be available through the package manager; Debian puts them in `coreutils` and `util-linux`, respectively) to lower the priority of the `find` process to the nicest levels possible, which means it should not interfere with anything else running on your system but will take slightly longer to complete. `find` itself will go through and `stat()` everything, which forces the kernel to load the file system data from disk into memory.

Once the cache has been built, as long as it doesn't get purged because the OS needs the memory for something else, it should be maintained. I've been using this for a while and directory listings even in large directories are *significantly* faster than without the above cron job, although I cannot cite any exact numbers.

Comment: If you're going to reinvent the wheel, you might as well use `locate`, which comes with `updatedb` to update a locate database: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)

Comment: @laebshade I don't use `locate` at all, but I use `ls` a lot. And occasionally `find`. (Also, find and ls are the specific commands the OP asks about.) The point of using `find` here is that it iterates over everything on storage calling stat(), so the kernel has to load the metadata into memory. Once it's there, it's as good as if it was stored across a reboot.