# "ls" command showing inode numbers for an NTFS partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, ntfs, inode

I have an NTFS partition mounted at `/media/disk`.

I run the following command: `ls -lai /media/disk`, and I got the following result:

[image]

The first column is for the inode number. But why is the inode number being shown, I thought that NTFS doesn't use inode numbers!

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Do not paste screenshots of commands. Put output in code block instead.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4950/117549

Answer (score 1):

What unix calls an inode number, NTFS calls an MFT record number.  Basically the index into the Master File Table that describes the file.