# Portable HDD not working

Tags: ubuntu, fsck, e2fsck

I just unplugged my portable WD hard drive without doing safe remove. I think that action of mine just corrupted my hdd.

I did the following:
`sudo fsck /dev/sdb1`

and I got the following result:
`

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I didn't really understand what that means.
Can anyone guide me what to do??

Comment: Are you sure your disk contains the right filesystem? Really ext4 or maybe NTFS, btrfs or xfs?

Comment: I did sudo fdisk -l
Type : HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Answer (score 0):

first: your drive is not NTFS ? you reformatted it to EXT4?

1. if it is NTFS (default file system)
   fixing NTFS with windows  `chkdsk` is best but this command works

   ```
   sudo ntfsfix  /dev/sdb1
   ```

   [NTFS-fix help](https://askubuntu.com/a/112161/613307)
2. if it's EXT4/EXT3/ext2 (you reformatted it)
   then the [super block](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4403/209801) is corrupt

it's saying the default  super block is corrupt so it can't check it,
 then is tells you to try a different super block,

tools like `testdisk` can be useful to restore a good super block,

Comment: @Pritam Bohra then use windows to [fix it ](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/)