# debugfs and "Bad magic number"

Tags: debian, filesystems, inode, debugfs

I'm trying to get file creation time using whatever I could find on the Internet and there's generally one solution that works for everybody, and this is the tutorial: https://tecadmin.net/file-creation-time-linux/

And this is where it goes wrong:

```sh
root@namename:/home/name# debugfs -R 'stat <33567136>' /dev/sda1
debugfs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1: Bad magic number in super-block while opening filesystem
stat: Filesystem not open
root@namename:/home/name#
```

I have no idea what to do with it, I'm a simple man, with simple wish, get 33567136's creation time (and every other file's afterwards).

When I Google this, results say that file system needs fixing because it is corrupted. However, my computer is working perfectly. There's nothing I can't access, no lag, no blocks, no inaccessibilities. It is also the only operating system.

I also weren't able to find clear tutorial on how to update debugfs in case of compatibility. `sudo apt-get install debugfs` and `apt-get install --only-upgrade debugfs`
 doesn't cut it: `E: Unable to locate package debugfs`. I weren't able to find the repo.

I would like to get the creation time, yet, can't because of issues I don't understand.

Comment: Linux `debugfs` only works for ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem types. If you're using a distribution that uses e.g. an XFS or BTRFS filesystem by default, `debugfs` will not work unless you've explicitly specified the filesystem type as ext2/3/4 when creating the filesystem (probably at OS installation time). Basically, the "bad magic number" error message means "this does not look like an ext2/3/4 filesystem". `debugfs` is typically part of the `e2fsprogs` package.

Comment: I had the same problem, but realized while reading this question that I had accidentally used `/dev/sdc` when I in fact meant to use `/dev/sdc1`

Answer (score 2):

As for the command  `debugfs -R 'stat <33567136>' /dev/sda1` failing when trying to fetch the info from inode 33567136:

- I suspect you are just following blindly the tutorial you are linking;
- copying the example verbatim to your system;
- and so, you do not have in fact, a file with an inode 33567136 on your system.

`stat` thus gives an error, which in turn makes `debugfs` spew out another error.

Forget the tutorial asking you for using the inode for finding out the file creation time. `stat` also accepts as argument file names.

Thus you can do it as:

```
$sudo debugfs -R 'stat /bin/ls' /dev/sda1
Inode: 97034   Type: regular    Mode:  0755   Flags: 0x0
Generation: 388006688    Version: 0x00000000:00000001
User:     0   Group:     0   Project:     0   Size: 130736
File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
Links: 1   Blockcount: 264
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x58bc61b1:cf0b33e8 -- Sun Mar  5 19:06:25 2017
 atime: 0x58bc61ac:00000000 -- Sun Mar  5 19:06:20 2017
 mtime: 0x58ad82d1:00000000 -- Wed Feb 22 12:23:45 2017
crtime: 0x58bc61b0:a1448018 -- Sun Mar  5 19:06:24 2017
Size of extra inode fields: 32
BLOCKS:
(0-11):196420-196431, (IND):164667, (12-15):196432-196435, (16-31):531568-531583
TOTAL: 33
```

I will point out however, from `man debugfs`, that `debugfs` only works with extfs file systems:

> NAME
>          debugfs - ext2/ext3/ext4 file system debugger
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The debugfs program is an interactive file system debugger. It can be used to  examine
>          and change the state of an ext2, ext3, or ext4 file system.

PS. As a reminder, if you have several partitions, the file system (/dev/sdax) has to match the partition where the file resides.

See also [What is a Superblock, Inode, Dentry and a File?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4402/what-is-a-superblock-inode-dentry-and-a-file)